# Why is my Luhn checksum calculated correctly on Windows but not on Android?

Tags: android, delphi

I get this `Luhn` function on Internet and it's correct when I compile it for Windows32 VCL. But when I compile it to use in an Android App I get a `False` instead of `True` and I suspect that it is because it is converting to `utf8` to byte expecting `ascii` to be converted.

So what can I do to this function in order to work correctly on Android?

```
function Luhn(Code: string): Boolean;
var
    i, sum: integer;
    temp: byte;
begin
{ calcula o algorítimo luhn, usado no iccid }
    sum := 0;
    for i:= length(Code) downto 1 do
    begin  // Run the characters backwards
      temp := byte(Code[i])-48;             // Convert from ASCII to byte
      if (length(Code)-i) mod 2 = 0
        then sum := sum + temp             // Odd characters just add
        else if temp < 5
           then sum := sum + 2*temp        // Even characters add double
           else sum := sum + (2*temp)-9;   // or sum the digits of the doubling
    end;
    Result := sum mod 10 = 0;              // Return true if sum ends in a 0
    if Result then
      Toast(Code+#13+'True')
    else
      Toast(Code+#13+'False');

end;
```

Comment: I think that the problem is actually somewhere else. The ASCII code for digits 0 to 9 are the same as the Unicode character codes.

Comment: I checked the same number 89550317000113572867 in VLC and FMX and I received True, then False.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that strings are zero based for the mobile compilers, by default, but one based for desktop compilers, by default. You need to adjust your code to account for that. Change

```
Code[i]
```

to

```
Code[i-1]
```

I recommend using

```
{$ZEROBASEDSTRINGS ON}
```

if you wish to share the code between mobile and desktop targets. Details here: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Zero-based_strings_(Delphi)

---

Some asides:

- There is no UTF-8 here at all.
- The code is desperately brittle and will fail horribly with code points outside the ASCII range. Some sanity checking would be prudent.
- I would suggest using `ord()` to get an ordinal value from a character.
- You might contemplate using the intrinsic `odd()` function rather than the explicit `mod` test.

---

So, I would personally write the code like this:

```
function LuhnChecksumValid(const Value: string): Boolean;
var
  C: Char;
  Digit: Integer;
  Sum: Integer;
  OddChar: Boolean;
begin
  if Value.Length=0 then
    Exit(False);

  Sum := 0;
  OddChar := odd(Value.Length);
  for C in Value do
  begin
    Digit := ord(C) - ord('0');
    if not InRange(Digit, 0, 9) then
      Exit(False);
    if OddChar then
      inc(Sum, Digit)
    else if Digit < 5 then
      inc(Sum, 2*Digit)
    else
      inc(Sum, 2*Digit - 9);
    OddChar := not OddChar;
  end;
  Exit((9*Sum) mod 10 = 0);
end;
```

Note that I have intentionally avoided using an index. Doing so allows us to completely side-step the issue of zero based or one based indices.

Comment: Er, that would break the mod test though wouldn't it? You'd need to change that if you changed the value of i.

Comment: Also, `X mod 2 = 0` is testing for an *even* value, but the code comments say it is testing  for an *odd* value instead.  So either the comment is wrong, or the code logic is wrong.

Comment: @Remy X is Length()-i. Which is the character index, zero based, counting in reverse. So X even corresponds to an odd character, once we switch to more human one based counting. So I think that the comment is right, albeit somewhat opaque.

Answer (score 6):

Like David said, this issue is related to the fact that the desktop and mobile compilers index strings differently by default.  Strings are still 1-indexed in the desktop compilers, but are 0-indexed by default in the mobile compilers.  This is described in the documentation:

[Migrating Delphi Code to Mobile from Desktop | Use 0-Based Strings](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE7/en/Migrating_Delphi_Code_to_Mobile_from_Desktop#Use_0-Based_Strings)

To make the code work in a way that you do not have to deal with ZBS differences, you can either:

1. use `{$ZEROBASEDSTRINGS OFF}` to go back to 1-based indexing on mobile

   ```
   {$IFDEF NEXTGEN}
     {$ZEROBASEDSTRINGS OFF}
   {$ENDIF}

   function Luhn(Code: string): Boolean;
   var
     i, sum: integer;
     temp: byte;
   begin
     { calcula o algorítimo luhn, usado no iccid }
     sum := 0;
     for i := Length(Code) downto 1 do begin  // Run the characters backwards
       temp := byte(Ord(Code[i]))-48;  // Convert from ASCII to byte
       if (Length(Code)-i) mod 2 = 0 then
         sum := sum + temp             // Odd characters just add
       else if temp < 5 then
         sum := sum + (2*temp)         // Even characters add double
       else
         sum := sum + (2*temp) - 9;    // or sum the digits of the doubling
     end;
     Result := sum mod 10 = 0;         // Return true if sum ends in a 0
     if Result then
       Toast(Code+#13+'True')
     else
       Toast(Code+#13+'False');
   end;

   {$IFDEF NEXTGEN}
     {$ZEROBASEDSTRINGS ON}
   {$ENDIF}
   ```
2. use the `Low(String)` and `High(String)` system functions:

   ```
   function Luhn(Code: string): Boolean;
   var
     i, sum: integer;
     temp: byte;
   begin
     { calcula o algorítimo luhn, usado no iccid }
     sum := 0;
     for i := High(Code) downto Low(Code) do begin  // Run the characters backwards
       temp := byte(Ord(Code[i]))-48;  // Convert from ASCII to byte
       if (High(Code)-i) mod 2 = 0 then
         sum := sum + temp             // Odd characters just add
       else if temp < 5 then
         sum := sum + (2*temp)         // Even characters add double
       else
         sum := sum + (2*temp) - 9;    // or sum the digits of the doubling
     end;
     Result := sum mod 10 = 0;         // Return true if sum ends in a 0
     if Result then
       Toast(Code+#13+'True')
     else
       Toast(Code+#13+'False');
   end;
   ```
3. use the `TStringHelper` helper class:

   ```
   uses
     ..., SysUtils;

   function Luhn(Code: string): Boolean;
   var
     i, sum: integer;
     temp: byte;
   begin
     { calcula o algorítimo luhn, usado no iccid }
     sum := 0;
     for i := Code.Length-1 downto 0 do begin  // Run the characters backwards
       temp := byte(Ord(Code.Chars[i]))-48;  // Convert from ASCII to byte
       if (Code.Length-1-i) mod 2 = 0 then
         sum := sum + temp             // Odd characters just add
       else if temp < 5 then
         sum := sum + (2*temp)         // Even characters add double
       else
         sum := sum + (2*temp) - 9;    // or sum the digits of the doubling
     end;
     Result := sum mod 10 = 0;         // Return true if sum ends in a 0
     if Result then
       Toast(Code+#13+'True')
     else
       Toast(Code+#13+'False');
   end;
   ```